# $AdS_3$ soliton of Witten - for Hawking-Page transition

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, holographic-principle, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, solitons

> Are there explicit AdS$_3$ soliton solution?

in the sense of [Witten's Anti De Sitter Space And Holography and Hawking-Page transition](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9802150) paper, by doing a
$$\tau_E, y ,r \to  y, \tau_E ,r$$

from a geometry with a Euclidean time $\tau_E$ cigar space and a compactified $y$ circle

[image]

to a geometry with a $y$ cigar space and a compactified Euclidean time $\tau_E$  circle

[image]

> If yes, with a AdS3 soliton solution, what are the form of solutions?
>
> If not, without a AdS3 soliton solution, what are the obstructions?

Answer (score 1):

There is an explicitly three-dimensional version of a Hawking-Page transition in AdS space. It is given by a transition between an asymptotically $AdS_3$ spacetime and the BTZ (Bañados-Teitelboim-Zanelli) black hole. The line element of thermal (euclidean) $AdS_3$ space is given by

$$ds^2=\left(1+r^2/L^2\right)dt^2+\left(1+r^2/L^2\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\phi^2,$$

where the periodicity of $t$ is given by the inverse temperature and $L$ is the $AdS$ radius. At a temperature that is determined by the point when the compact circles of both geometries match, the system undergoes a phase transition to the BTZ black hole geometry given by

$$ds^2=\left(-M+r^2/L^2\right)dt^2+\left(-M+r^2/L^2\right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\phi^2,$$

with $M$ as the mass of the black hole.